# How to add two numbers in javascript using HTML code?

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like 1 2 3 4 5.... in loop but it starts from 0 . So, for that i want to add +1 in every loop for indexes.
I have tried

```
for(a in group[i]){

            output+=
                "<tr class='rem1'>"
        +         "<td class='invert'>"+ a + 1 +"</td>";
}
```

but gives me "0+1" in browser.

Comment: `"+ (+a + 1) +"`

Comment: it's very common to see. javascript actually coerce your a + 1 as strings and joins `01` as strings to solve this you can wrap it in parenthesis `(a + 1)` or `parseInt(a + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals, and avoid the string concatenations, or parentheses to escape from the outer string concatenation operation.